# how to improve jquery's performance or use regular replace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to add prefix id to all DOM element's several attributes.

what is the best way ?

I found jquery's find and each function is slow.
should I use regular replace ?

jquery's code for example:

```
$("body").find("id").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id", "AAA_" + $(this).attr("id"));
});

$("body").find("label[for]").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("for", "AAA_" + $(this).attr("for"));
});
```

Comment: Putting `$(this)` in a variable should make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

First, you're looking for `id` elements, not elements with an `id` attribute. Use [`[id]`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector) instead.

Second, use the callback argument to [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr):

```
$('[id]').attr('id', function(idx, oldId) {
    return 'AAA_' + oldId;
});
$('label[for]').attr('for', function(idx, oldFor) {
    return 'AAA_' + oldFor;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your selector to (i assume only imputs) and do it all in one loop

```
$('input').each(function(){
    var cur_id = this.id;
    $('label[for:="'+cur_id +'"]').attr('for',"AAA_" + cur_id  );
    cur_id  = "AAA_" + cur_id ;
});
```

Comment: `$this = this.id` is confusing. I believe most would expected `$this` to be defined as `$this = $(this)`. How about `curId = this.id` instead?

Comment: You're still introducing confusion. The convention of prepending a `$` to a variable name is to indicate that the variable stores a jQuery object. You are not storing a jQuery object, merely a reference to the id property of the currently selected element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to modify HTML attribute values, or do you want to modify DOM properties? I suspect that you actually want to deal with DOM properties.

The following will add a prefix to nominated DOM properties if that property has a value other than empty string. Be careful, some properties are boolean, adding a string prefix may have unusual results.

I'd be interested to know how much faster this is than jQuery.

```
function prefixProperty(prop, prefix) {
  var el, els = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
  var i = els.length;

  while (i--) {
    el = els[i];

    // Only modify property if it has a value other than empty string
    if (el[prop].length) {
      el[prop] = prefix + el[prop];
    }
  }
}
```